# Please check my proof that subset of countable set is countable

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, self-learning

[image]So, $ n_2 = \min ( (n \in \mathbb{N} |f(n) ) - f(n_1)  )  $

So $ n_{i-1} = \min ( (n \in \mathbb{N} |f(n) ) - f(n_1)  )  $

Define $g : \mathbb{N} \to A$

$g(1)= f(n_1)$

$g(i)=f(n_i)$

To check g is one - one fucntion

Assume $g(i)=g(j)$

$\implies f(n_i)=f(n_j)$

$\implies n_i=n_j$ (As f is one one)

$\implies i = j  $ (I am not quite sure about this step )

To check f is ONTO

Consider $f(n_i) \in A$. Since $A \subseteq B$. So $f(n_i) \in B$

Since f in Onto. So $\exists a  n \in \mathbb{N} $ such that $n_i \in N $ for some $i$.

Is this correct ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is correct. The intuition is that if $B$ is countable, then one can enumerate the elements of $B$ using natural numbers:
$$ b_0, b_1, \ldots, b_n, \ldots \in B.$$
Formally, there is a function $f: \mathbb{N} \to B$. You can think that $b_n = f(n)$, if you want to.

If $A$ is an infinite subset of $B$, then every element $a$ in $A$ will be equal to $f(n)$ for some unique $n$. Thus you can enumerate the elements in $A$, using the enumeration $f$ of $B$. This enumeration is the function $g$ that you have defined.

Note that the assumption that $A$ is infinite is required: otherwise the definition of $g$ wouldn't work.

Comment: In your last line, is this because if Ais finite then then g will not be one to one ?

Comment: It's worse. If $A$ is finite, then 
$$\{ n : f(n) \in A \} \setminus \{ n_0, n_1, \ldots, n_i \}$$
is empty for some $i$.

Comment: How so  ? i didnot understand

Comment: Remember how $g$ is defined. 
1. Take the enumeration $f$ of $B$ and let $g(0)$ be the first element in the enumeration of $B$ which belongs to $A$.
2. Let $g(1)$ be the second element in the enumeration of $B$ which belongs to $A$.
3. In general, let $g(n)$ be the $n+1$:th element in the enumeration of $B$ which belongs to $A$
If $A$ is finite there will be some $n$ so that there is no $n+1$:th element in the enumeration of $B$ which belongs to $A$. In this case, the function $g$ will not be defined for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: ok i see now.....

Comment: In other words we will exhaust n's and other n's will be left unused , so function definition is not proper here as some n's are left . Hope this is correct